# use readStream in Spark 1.6?

Tags: scala, sockets, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am noob in spark, trying to read the data from a socket in Spark 1.6.0.

Following is my code doing is -

```
val sqc = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val socketop = sqc.readStream.format("socket").option("myhost","localhost").option("port",1111).load
```

But I receive error as shown below -

> readStream is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> readStream.format("socket")
> ```

It won't work in Spark 1.6.0 as Spark Structured Streaming that this code is part of is only available as of Spark 2.0 and later.

Quoting [Input Sources](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources):

> In Spark 2.0, there are a few built-in sources.
>
> **Socket source (for testing)** - Reads UTF8 text data from a socket connection. The listening server socket is at the driver. Note that this should be used only for testing as this does not provide end-to-end fault-tolerance guarantees.

In order to read *"the data from a socket in Spark 1.6.0"* you have to use [Spark Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) (which I personally consider dead and recommend not using it unless you have to).

Comment: Thanks Jacek,
Can you please share what drove you to consider Spark Streaming dead? Is there a better alternative you'd rather use. I want to know!

Comment: _"A better alternative"_ you ask? That...is... **Spark 2.2** with **Structured Streaming**. That's the future and where all the development is focused on. Upgrade to 2.2 (since 1.6 is dead too, esp. 1.6.0). Spark Streaming's not announced as such, but you can read the recent answers from the leading developers (Michael and TD) and you will know.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this it is using spark 1.6, it may help you
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example

Comment: Thank you so much, but I will upgrade to spark 2